# Why can't I reference this array index that seems to exist?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting a return string from a merchant account that looks like:

```
RecurringID=8675309&RefNo=41:39&Notes=
```

so I parse it into an array like this:

```
$results = array();
$temp = explode('&', $temp);
foreach($temp as $line)
{
    $line = explode('=', $line);
    $results[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
}
```

The resulting **print_r($results);** produces this:

```
Array ( [RecurringID] => 8675309 [RefNo] => 41:39 [Notes] => )
```

And yet when I try this:

```
$blah = $results['RecurringID'];
```

I get:

```
Notice (8) : Undefined index:  RecurringID
```

Comment: Is all of the above code in the same code block/function? Or are the $results being passed from the Controller and you're trying to access it in the View? If this is the case, you'll need to access it through the View object. Post all of the related code if this is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! My problem was outputing it to the browser, I couldn't see the full return value. 
Turns out looking at the ascii values reveals:

```
\r\n\t\t<html><body>RecurringID=1488819&RefNo=186:192&Notes=</body></html>
```

Which apparently was confusing parse_str and my manual method for parsing.

Comment: `invisible character in the return` ...or in your code. Seems like the most logical explanation. At least Cake doesn't have anything to do with this. Try `var_dump(array_flip($results))` to check the length of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this error. Are you using it it before the `RecurringID` index is defined?

Do you know about [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

```
$temp = 'RecurringID=8675309&RefNo=41:39&Notes=';
parse_str($temp, $results);

print "<pre>";
print_r($results);
print "</pre>";
```

`$results` has this in it:

```
Array
(
    [RecurringID] => 8675309
    [RefNo] => 41:39
    [Notes] => 
)
```

This works fine:

```
print $results['RecurringID']; //8675309
```

I can't replicate your warning even if I add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

...above everything else.

Comment: I suspect he did. The code is in the logical order ( reference to RecurringID is at the bottom). I suspect cakephp is doing something crazy to my array.